# What is the django drop down type?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I Want to know:
What is the django drop down type?

if we add dropdown and add class so should we need to pass this

```
widgets = {
    'Currency':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
}
```

or something?

**I'M USING MODEL FORM**

**I NEED TO KNOW TYPE FOR EXAMPLE TEXTINPUT OR SOMETHING I WANT TO STYLE IT**

Because when i pass this my dropdown convert into input i don't need like that

**i just need to know what is the drop down type** for example TextInput or something

**QUESTION IN 1 LINE:** I Want To STYLE MY CHOICE FIELD SO TO STYLE So WE NEED TO PASS SOMETHING LIKE THIS `forms.TextInput` so I Need To Know What is choice field type is it TextInput or something!

Any Help Will Be Appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use CAPS in your questions like this. It's impolite and difficult to read. Also, this question is answered in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/).

Comment: @dirkgroten i'm very sorry again i will never user thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) which renders as a select html element by default.

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=..)
```

If you are using ModelForm:

```
 class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.all())
```

EDIT: ChoiceField use the `forms.Select` widget like this:

```
field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = '', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'your_class'}))
```

Comment: No I'm using model form

Comment: i need type to style it for example text Input or something

Comment: to add class first we need to add type for example texinput email input something so i want to know what is the type of ChoiceField

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede I Need The Type of that for example Text input or something

Answer (score 1):

`Select` is the widget for choicefield.

from [***docs***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/fields/#ChoiceField):

```
class ChoiceField(Field):
    widget = Select
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_choice': _('Select a valid choice. %(value)s is not one of the available choices.'),
    }
```